# How to use managed identity to access key vault on different subscription of same tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, azure-security

Have my Azure VM scale set on **subscription1** of tenantA & assigned user managed identity which also belongs to subscription1 of tenantA.

Now I have keyvault on **subscription2** of tenantA(same tenant). The keyvault hold secrets which the apps on Azure VM scale set on **subscription1** needs to access.

It is possible to add managed identity Azure VM scale set on **subscription1** to the access policy of the keyvault on **subscription2** of same tenant as per the below answer.

Is it possible to add managed identity Azure VM scale set on **subscription1** to the access policy of the keyvault on **subscription2** of **different directory/tenant**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
A Managed Identity creates a service principal in the Azure AD tenant of its subscription.
That service principal can be granted access to anything within that Azure AD tenant, including all subscriptions linked to it.

Comment: any link to know the steps involved to achieve it?

Comment: After creating the managed identity, you can go to the Key Vault to add the access policy. When selecting the principal, search for the managed identity name.

Comment: modified my question.